# How split word in rows Mysql

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to split a word into separate lines? All the examples I found were using something to refer to as a comma or something, but I would like to separate each letter from a word, eg:

from (my table):

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | banana |

to: `SELECT ...`

| id | letter |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | n |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | n |
| 1 | a |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is doing it with a recursive query, using the following two steps:

- base step: get the letter in position 1
- recursive step: get nth letter, using `LEFT(RIGHT(1), n)`, which extracts the letter in position n.

Recursion is halted when the nth extracting element is higher than then length of the string.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT id, name,
           1 AS idx, 
           RIGHT(LEFT(name, 1),1) AS letter 
    FROM tab
  
    UNION ALL
  
    SELECT id, name,
           idx + 1 AS idx,
           RIGHT(LEFT(name, idx+1), 1) AS letter
    FROM cte
    WHERE idx < LENGTH(name)
)
SELECT id, letter FROM cte
```

Output:

| id | letter |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | n |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | n |
| 1 | a |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oKVL7fHbk8BhozXbMkPupy/0).

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to join with a numbers table:

```
with n as (
   select * from (values row(1),row(2),row(3),row(4),row(5),row(6),row(7),row(8),row(9))x(num)
)
select t.id, Substring(name, n.num, 1)
from t
join n on n.num <= Length(t.name);
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cRp8InmI)

Comment: But in this case, from what I understand, the amount of `row(i)` that I put in the query is limited, so much so that in your example I increased the characters of the word and only brought 9 lines correct?

Comment: The CTE is an example of how to use a numbers table - you can either add enough to the cte to cater for the largest length string or use a permanent table of numbers, a common pattern often referred to as a *Tally Table*

Answer (score 0):

An other way more performant is by using `REGEXP_REPLACE`, `json_array` and `json_table`

`REGEXP_REPLACE` to convert **banana** to **b,n,a,n,a**

`json_array` to create a json array from **b,n,a,n,a**

`json_table` will convert JSON data to tabular data.

```
with cte as (
  select id, REGEXP_REPLACE(name, "(.)(?!$)", "$1,") as name
   from _table
)
select cte.id, t.name
from cte
join json_table(
  replace(json_array(cte.name), ',', '","'),
  '$[*]' columns (name varchar(50) path '$')
) t;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ahyB7a6h)